# PHP errors on if syntax

Tags: php, if-statement

Hmm
I learned that 'Learning PHP' that the '=' operator returns the right side value
for example, A=1234 returns 1234.

so I edited

```
if($oper1 && $oper2){
```

to

```
if($oper1 = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'operand1', FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT) &&
    $oper2 = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'operand2', FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT)){
```

Did I make a mistake???

the entire source code is below:

```
if($oper1 = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'operand1', FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT) && 
   $oper2 = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'operand2', FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT)){ 
    //if($oper1 && $oper2){ 
        switch($_POST['op']){ 
            case 'ADD': 
                print $oper1+$oper2; 
                break; 
            case 'SUB': 
                print $oper1-$oper2; 
                break; 
            case 'MUL': 
                print $oper1*$oper2; 
                break; 
            case 'DIV': 
                print $oper1/$oper2; 
                break; 
        } 
}
```

Comment: the entire source is

Comment: What makes you think you have made a mistake? Tell us what you think is wrong with your new code

Comment: = is assignment operator in php use == to fulfil a condition

Comment: What is the error or problem you encounter?

Comment: Are you sure the data is in the $_POST array? Show us how you set the values into `$oper1` and `$oper2` before you changed the code

Comment: @RiggsFolly yeah I sure. I only changed one line and it made a new error.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I think the two expressions are same, but latter doesn't work!

Comment: Sorry, I didn't put the initialization code.

Comment: the original code was
$oper1 = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'operand1', FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT);
$oper2 = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'operand2', FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT);

if($oper1 && $oper2){

Comment: WishSKY please update your question rather than putting code and explanation into comments.  Cheers

Comment: If your variables may be zero `$oper !== FALSE` would be more correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `=` operator has a lower priority than the `&&` operator in PHP. Therfore the `&&` command is evaluated before the `=` command. That creates a behavior for your code, that is equivalent to the following code:

```
$oper2 = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'operand2', FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT);
$oper1 = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'operand1', FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT) && $oper2;
if ($oper1) { ... }
```

Since that is clearly not what you want, you should separate the initialization of the variables form the if condition. This is also way more readable.

[PHP operator priorities](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php)

Comment: Alternative is `if(($oper1 = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'operand1', FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT)) && 
   ($oper2 = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'operand2', FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT))){` but that's not as readable as separating the assignment from the if

Comment: Thanks!! it was because of operator priority!!

Comment: @MarkBaker Thanks for your detail advice.